# Wrestling with PROC REPORT and summary lines

Tags: sas

I am having trouble getting `proc report` to do quite what I want.

I have a table with `state`, `item`, `counts`, percentage by state and percentage of total.  There are summary lines giving the total by state and a grand total.  My problem is that those summary lines summarize the state totals at the grand total level. like so:

CODE:

```
proc report data=dataset nowd ;
columns state item count pct_state percent;

define state /order 'State';
define item / 'Status';
define count / '#';
define pct_state / '% of State';
define percent / '% of Total';

break after state/ol summarize;
compute after state;
  item=catt(state,' Total');
  state = '';
  line @1 ' ';
endcomp;
rbreak after /ol summarize;
compute after;
  involved = 'Grand Total';
endcomp;
run;
```

Makes a table like this:

```
State  Item   #  %state  %total
AL      A     2   40.0%   20.0%
        B     3   60.0%   30.0%
     AL Total 5  100.0%   50.0%

MN      A     1   20.0%   10.0%
        B     1   20.0%   10.0%
        C     3   60.0%   30.0%
     MN Total 5  100.0%   50.0%

Grand Total   10 200.0%  100.0%
```

As you can see, it reports the state % total as 200% which is a nonsensical number.  I would prefer to have it not summarize the state value at all.  I know that the sas website warns about using dates on tables with summary lines since SAS interprets them as numerical variables and thus summarizes them...but it doesn't provide a good solution.  I really don't understand why the `BREAK` and `RBREAK` statements don't have a "VAR" option that lets you specify...but now I need a workaround.

What I have come up with is to make a new variable and store the percentage as text so that it can't be computed in the summary but this is a really backwards way to do it.

```
data dataset; set dataset;
  state_txt = trim(left(put(pct_state,percent10.1)));
run;

proc report data=dataset nowd ;
columns state item count state_txt percent;

define state /order 'State';
define item / 'Status';
define count / '#';
define state_txt / right '% of State';
define percent / '% of Total';

break after state/ol summarize;
compute after state;
  item=catt(state,' Total');
  state = '';
  line @1 ' ';
endcomp;
rbreak after /ol summarize;
compute after;
  involved = 'Grand Total';
endcomp;
run;
```

This eliminates all of the summaries (since it is a character variable) but it seems like just a terrible way of doing things when I should be able to say something like `rbreak after /summarize var=count percent;` and be done with it. Is there any better way to do it?  Also, I wouldn't mind if it summarized on the per state level to 100%...its not a priority though and is far less important than getting it to NOT say 200% on the bottom (or in the case of a full USA table, 5000%).

**Sample data:**

```
data dataset;
 length state item $50;
 infile datalines delimiter=','; 
 input state item $ count percent pct_state;
 datalines;  
  AL,A,8,0.0047,1.0000
  DC,A,1,0.0006,0.5000
  DC,B,1,0.0006,0.5000
  FL,A,18,0.0107,0.7500
  FL,B,2,0.0012,0.0833
  FL,C,4,0.0024,0.1667
  LA,A,434,0.2576,0.8314
  LA,B,69,0.0409,0.1322
  LA,C,19,0.0113,0.0364
  MI,A,1,0.0006,1.0000
  MS,A,4,0.0024,0.8000
  MS,B,1,0.0006,0.2000
  OK,A,2,0.0012,1.0000
  PA,A,1,0.0006,1.0000
  TX,A,943,0.5596,0.8435
  TX,B,132,0.0783,0.1181
  TX,C,43,0.0255,0.0385
  VA,A,1,0.0006,1.0000
  WI,B,1,0.0006,1.0000
  ;
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data? Makes it easier to work with your report code...

Comment: Added sample data--percentages may not quite add up to 100 as I rounded them to 4 decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using some if logic in your COMPUTE AFTER will do the trick.
Try this (I changed the data slighty, let me know if this doesn't represent your data):

(Left in the out= statement, which can be helpful)

```
data dataset;
 length state item $50;
 infile datalines delimiter=','; 
 input state item $ count percent pct_state;
 format percent pct_state percent10.1;
 datalines;  
  AL,A,8,0.8,1.0000
  DC,A,1,0.1,0.5000
  DC,B,1,0.1,0.5000
 ;

proc report data=dataset nowd out=work.report;
 columns state item count pct_state percent;

  define state /order 'State';
  define item / 'Status';
  define count / '#';
  define pct_state / '% of State';
  define percent / '% of Total';

  break after state/ol summarize;
  compute after state;
   item=catt(state,' Total');
   state = '';
   line @1 ' ';
  endcomp;

  rbreak after /ol summarize;
  compute after;
   State = 'Grand Total';
   if pct_state.sum>1 then pct_state.sum=1;
  endcomp;

 run;
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I will change it a bit more to just say `pct_state.sum = ''` in the rbreak's compute block (and maybe in the per-state compute as well).  I had tried to do this before with just pct_state=''; and it didn't work--I was missing the ".sum"